# Magento 2.3 Dashboard Grand Total data

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, dashboard

By default Magento 2.3 dashboard have revenue, tax, shipping and quantity data under the chart.

I found that `/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Dashboard/Totals.php` have rows

```
    $this->addTotal(__('Revenue'), $totals->getRevenue());
    $this->addTotal(__('Tax'), $totals->getTax());
    $this->addTotal(__('Shipping'), $totals->getShipping());
    $this->addTotal(__('Quantity'), $totals->getQuantity() * 1, true);
```

How can I add "Grand Total (Base)" data to Dashboard?

I tried add `$this->addTotal(__('Grand Total'), $totals->getGrandTotal());` but no any result

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: why grand total in dashboard ??

Comment: Because of business specific I need this metric on dashboard.